# servo robotic arm using arduino and bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-c++, hc-05

I am trying to control servo robotic arm via bluetooth module hc05.
All things connected properly. I am confused which control app will use.
And also bluetooth does not send any data to arduino but light is blinking.
If any one have robotic arm code, please share

I have tried almost all code from different website.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> // TX RX software library for bluetooth

#include <Servo.h> // servo library 
Servo myservo1, myservo2, myservo3, myservo4; // servo name

int bluetoothTx = 10; // bluetooth tx to 10 pin
int bluetoothRx = 11; // bluetooth rx to 11 pin

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
```

just need any app for controlling servo from Bluetooth,also trying to sent data from Bluetooth but nothing happened.

Comment: First of all, for debugging you can try to send data to your Bluetooth throw serial monitor in Arduino ide. If it answers correctly, there is `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class for communication

Comment: Thats C/C++, not C#. Please do not confuse tags

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really much to go on here. Does the servo work from the Arduino without the Bluetooth module connected? Do you have 1k and 2k resistors on the RX pin of the Bluetooth to lower the logic level? What about power?

Here's the connections that need to be made with the HC-05:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7I3x.png

Don't worry about the EN pin though. No need to connect that to anything.

As for code, look up the default servo controlling examples in the Arduino IDE and then add Bluetooth functionality to it.

Do you also have a way to communicate with the board? Some sort of app to send commands to the Arduino?

Here's someone that has done this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gL7b8E_5aYs

He has a link to the app and his code in the description.

In regards to your robotic arm, here's "How to Mechatronics". This guy makes instructive and easy to follow Arduino videos. Here is his robotic arm video. (source code and app in description etc.):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B3gWd3A_SI

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on your bluetooth on both device?
Did you pair it together?

And do you know about AT Command Mode in Bluetooth? 
its good to know when you have problem about connection and password.

I am using arduino bluetooth RC Car for my robot arduino, you can use it too for robotic arm testing connection.